# JQuery append method not adding html to the page

Tags: jquery, validation, model-view-controller, textarea, blur

I am loading a view using Ajax/jQuery. This view contains a form having jquery validation in it. My problem is the error messages are not displayed if I try to submit an invalid form.

The page has a text area in it and a submit button. The validation event is fired and an error is reported if text area is empty. The text area is focused with the cursor but error message is not displayed. When I click somewhere else on the page or outside the page only then the error message is displayed. Basically error message is showing on the onBlur event of the textarea although I don't have any blur event for this textarea.

Can someone relate to this?

My code is like this:

```
errorPosition = $("#frm").validate();

errorPosition.settings.errorPlacement = function (error, element)
{
   $("#errordiv").html(error);
}
```

The error is displayed only after textarea is blurred.

Comment: You're going to have to post more code. In what you posted, the `$("#errordiv").html(error);` doesn't get executed, the function is only assigned to a variable. Have you tried stepping through it using Firebug/Google's DevTools/IE's developer tools?

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use the `errorLabelContainer` [option](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) instead of `errorPlacement`, and call it like this:

```
$("#frm").validate({
    errorLabelContainer:'#errordiv'
});
```

This will take care of hiding and showing your errors properly.